# Selected rows always resetting when click on toggle sidebar

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, html-table, react-table, react-table-v7

Please find the code link https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-phoebe-ux3e5?file=/src/nestead-table/index.js

select any records from the table and then click on the Toggle side bar the selected checkbox is getting reset always.

Please help Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's way too much code to expect someone doing debugging. Try to isolate the problematic code and ask your question. A hint: are you using state to manage the boxes that are ticked?

Comment: As above, please reduce this to a more manageable minimum viable example. That aside, have you looked into [autoResetSelectedRows](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#table-options)?

Answer (score 1):

Add autoResetSelectedRows: false, autoResetSelectedCell: false, and autoResetSelectedColumn: false. That will fix the problem you have.

```
function Table({ columns: userColumns, data }) {
const {
  getTableProps,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  rows,
  prepareRow,
  page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
  // which has only the rows for the active page

  // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
  canPreviousPage,
  canNextPage,
  pageOptions,
  pageCount,
  gotoPage,
  nextPage,
  previousPage,
  setPageSize,
  selectedFlatRows,
  state: { pageIndex, pageSize }
} = useTable(
  {
    columns: userColumns,
    data,
    initialState: { hiddenColumns: excludeColoumns, pageIndex: 0 }
    // Here you can add
    autoResetSelectedRows: false,
    autoResetSelectedCell: false,
    autoResetSelectedColumn: false,
  },
  useSortBy,
  usePagination,
  useRowSelect,
```